# How to get all available cameras with actionscript?

Tags: actionscript

I can get the default camera this way:

```
Camera.getCamera();
```

But how to get all available cameras connected to my computer with actionscript?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Camera.names` array to get the list of cameras supported on the system. `Camera.getCamera()` returns a reference to the default camera.

Using the Camera.names array, you can call `Camera.getCamera(name:String = null)` and pass the name of the camera to it. To specify a name, use the string representation of the zero-based index position within the Camera.names array. For example, to specify the third camera in the array, use `Camera.getCamera("2")`.

More info : [flash.media.Camera : Adobe Livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Camera.html)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately only the selected camera (via Adobe Flash Player Settings) is available to ActionScript.

Comment: Sorry, you don't have access to that in AS3, only the user can switch cameras.

Answer (score -1):

```
trace(Camera.names);
```

Don't you have code hinting?